# Exception on install msmqdistributor for Enterprise Library 6

Tags: msmq, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

I am trying to install msmqdistributor service for Enterprise Library 6, but got this exception:

```
An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the C:\EntLib\MsmqDistributor.exe assembly.
The inner exception System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..
```

That requested types it is looking for?

Thanks much for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have solved it myself. Hope this may help other people who wanted to use MSMQ for logging out.

I re-downloaded the source code, and using the batch command to recompiled the whole Enterprise Library 6. This generated a working msmqdistributor.exe.

Please note, I also recompiled the source code from the LAB solution, and that did not work.